# Collect collections by partitions from DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, collections, partitioning

I have DataFrame partitioned by column:

```
val dfDL = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",")
                     .option("header", true)
                     .csv(file.getPath.toUri.getPath)
                     .repartition(col("column_to"))

val structure =  "schema_from" ::
                 "table_from"  ::
                 "column_from" ::
                 "link_type"   ::
                 "schema_to"   ::
                 "table_to"    ::
                 "column_to"   :: Nil
```

How do I get a collection of arrays by partitions?
That is, for each partition I need a collection.
For example I need this method:

```
def getArrays(df: DataFrame): Iterator[Array] = { //Or Iterator[List]
   ???
}
```

All value for partition:

```
val allTargetCol = df.select(col("column_to")).distinct().collect().map(_.getString(0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the partition values, you can iterate over each partition value, call filter and then collect.

pseudo code

```py
partitions = []

for partition_value in partition_values_list:
  partitions.append(df.filter(f.col('partiton_column') == partition_value).collect())
```

Otherwise, you need to first make a list/array of distinct partition values and then repeat the above step.

Comment: Yes, i know partition values. allTargetCol.

Comment: Ya then simply iterate over it as given pseudo code above (updated the answer).

Comment: This is good idea . Thanks! But I need to used only immutable collections from Scala )

Comment: I understand you idea. I try do it

Comment: After `.collect()` there should be option to convert into immutable collections.